# Генерация синхронных extensions с помощью Roslyn

Tags: c#, синтаксический-анализ, кодогенераторы

Привет. Предположим, есть какой-то интерфейс `IInterface`. Выглядит он примерно так:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    ISubInterface<MyClass> SubInterface { get; }
    ISubInterface<MyClass2> SubInterface2 { get; }

    ISecondSubInterface<MyClass> SecondSubInterface { get; }
}
```

В свою очередь, `ISubInterface<T>` выглядит примерно так (`ISecondSubInterface<T>` выглядит так же, не суть):

```
public interface ISubInterface<T> where T : class
{
    Task<Result<T>> GetAsync(string arg1, TimeSpan? timeout = null);
}
```

Хотелось бы кодогенерацией решить следующую задачу:
1) Получить все интерфейсы, которые являются типами свойств в `IInterface`
2) Сгенерировать для них класс с синхронными extensions вида:

```
public static SubInterfaceExtensions
{        
    public static Result<T> Get<T>(this ISubInterface<T> i, string arg1, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        return i.GetAsync(arg1, timeout).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Задача кажется не сложной, разбивается на подзадачи:
1) Найти все интерфейсы из `IInterface`
2) Получить полную информацию о сигнатурах методов, причём в `IInterface` они закрытые generics, а информация нужна еще о незакрытом
3) На основе полученных сигнатур построить новые методы-расширения и засунуть их в соотв. класс

Насколько для этих задач подходит Roslyn и если подходит, то как примерно это всё может выглядеть?

Comment: На всякий случай - `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - это верный способ получить дедлок при вызове из asp.net -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007006/is-getawaiter-getresult-safe-for-general-use

Comment: Технически, кодогенерация посредством Roslyn API вполне возможна. [Вот вам пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/756891/10105), адаптируйте. Но синхронная обёртка для асинхронной функции — это [не лучшая идея](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/).