# Дизайн API: Реализация подобия LINQ to XML с элементами, имеющими свойства

Tags: c#, .net, консоль, linq2xml, дизайн-api

#### Введение

Я работаю над библиотекой [CsConsoleFormat](https://github.com/Athari/CsConsoleFormat), которая выводит иерархические документы в консоль. Для построения документов поддерживаются XAML и API сродни LINQ to XML. Мне нужен **чистый, краткий, понятный** API, так как основная цель библиотеки — сделать сложное форматирование простым. Более того, API по возможности должен **стимулировать написание читаемого кода**.

Класс `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` имеет конструктор, принимающий аргумент `params object[] content` и применяющий к нему следующие преобразования: схлопнуть последовательности в элементы, пропустить null, преобразовать строки к текстовым нодам, добавить элементы и атрибуты как есть, всё остальное преобразовать к строкам.

#### Проблема

Моя библитека полагается на тот же подход с `params object[] content`, но вместо конструктора используется метод `AddChildren`. Причины этому следующие:

1. Конструкторы с аргументами вроде `params object[] content` могут показаться неестественными тем, кто работает с XAML. Проблема становится более острой, если я добавляю осмысленные конструкторы — придётся во все конструкторы добавлять этот аргумент.
2. В отличие от `XElement`, у моих элементов есть полноценные свойства, которые удобно писать в инициализаторе. И если `new Span("Yellow") { Color = Yellow }` выглядит нормально, то при появлении иерархии логическая последовательность теряется:

   ```
   new Document(
       new Span("Title") { Color = White },
       new Grid() {
           // ... очень длинный документ
       }
       new Span("Footer")
   ) {
       Color = Yellow,
   }
   ```

   Внезапно после прочтения всего документа вы замечаете, что все элементы унаследовали жёлтый цвет от корневого элемента. Более того, библиотека поддерживает прикреплённые свойства (например, `Grid.Column`), которые можно задать только после вызова конструктора (при помощи метода-расширения `Set`).

   При использовании метода `AddChildren` логическая последовательность сохраняется:

   ```
   new Document {
       Color = Yellow,
   }.AddChildren(
       new Span("Title") { Color = White },
       new Grid { /* ... */ }
           .AddChildren(
               // ... очень длинный документ
           )
       new Span("Footer")
   )
   ```

   Однако если оставить только `AddChildren`, то краткий код вроде этого:

   ```
   new Div(DateTime.Now),
   new Div(DateTime.Now) { TextAlign = Left },
   ```

   становится более многословным:

   ```
   new Div().AddChildren(DateTime.Now),
   new Div { TextAlign = Left }.AddChildren(DateTime.Now),
   ```

#### Вопросы

1. Существует ли подход, объединяющий как можно больше достоинств и избегающий как можно больше недостатков из перечисленных выше?
2. Если я решу включить и конструкторы, и `AddChildren`, есть ли какой-нибудь способ заставить/мотивировать кодера писать код в соответствии со стилем, описанным выше (конструктор для одиноких однострочных детей, метод для сложного содержимого)? Анализаторы кода Roslyn для этого сгодятся?

#### Заметки

1. Мне известен ещё более простой API — методы-расширения а-ля [npm/colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors). Однако похоже, что этот способ применим только в узком подмножестве случаев, так что проблема остаётся.

<sub>Кросс-пост: [API design issues - Implementing API similar to LINQ to XML with elements having properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103600/api-design-issues-implementing-api-similar-to-linq-to-xml-with-elements-having).</sub>

Comment: Анализаторы прекрасно подходят, да. У меня где-то был пример на далёкую тему, сейчас найду.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/756891/10105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если цель - все делать как в Linq to XML, то свойства элементов являются очевидным аналогом атрибутов. А значит, с ними можно обойтись так же как и с атрибутами:

```
new Document(
    new ColorProperty(Yellow),
    new Span("Title", new ColorProperty(White)),
    new Grid() {
        // ... очень длинный документ
    }
    new Span("Footer")
)
```

Однако, я не считаю Linq to XML эталоном понятности API - а потому вовсе не обязательно делать все как сделано там. В конце концов, в C# есть и более типизированные варианты сделать то же самое:

```
new Document
{
    Color = Yellow,
    Children = {
        new Span("Title") { Color = White },
        new Grid {

        },
        "Footer",
    },
}
```

С прикрепленными свойствами можно обойтись похожим образом:

```
new Span("Foo") {
    AttachedProperties = {
        { Grid.ColumnProperty, 1 },
    },
}
```

Напомню, что для использования Collection Initializer в C# тип должен обладать методом Add и реализовывать интерфейс IEnumerable - причем эти два требования никак не связаны друг с другом: можно реализовать произвольное количество перегрузок метода Add с любым количеством параметров и любыми типами этих параметров.

Comment: Первый способ выглядит мерзко, если честно: куча типов, никакой наглядности.  По второму: у меня сейчас `Children` типа `ElementCollection : ElementCollection<Element> : Collection<Element>`. Вы мне предлагаете делать `Collection<Object>`, что "типизированным" назвать сложно. Кроме того, есть прикреплённые свойства, которые всё равно улетят в конец: `new Element(/*...*/).Set(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1)`.

Comment: @Athari не обязательно делать `Collection<Object>` - достаточно перегруженного метода `Add`.

Comment: Мне нравится идея с инициализаторами коллекций. Коллекция элементов и так реализует explicit IList.Add (правда с другой реализацией и для поддержки XAML...), а для прикреплённых свойств я пока рассматриваю вариант пустышки чисто для добавления свойств (внутренее представление коллекции прикреплённых свойств слишком недружелюбно, а перетаскивать дружелюбные методы в обёртку — только усложнять синтаксис). Эта штука ведь в C# и VB поддерживается одинаково именно в таком виде (IEnumerable + Add)?

Comment: @Athari про VB ничего не знаю

Comment: Попробовал. Выглядит действительно чистенько, мне нравится. Малину портит только тот факт, что шарп (ну или дотнет) не умеет в дженериковые  индексаторы. В отличие от инициализаторов коллекций, инициализаторы словарей совмещаются с инициализаторами объектов, но полагаются на индексаторы, а `this<T>(AttachedProperty<T> property, T value)` написать не удаётся, и прикреплённые свойства получаются нетипизированными. Вариант `Add<T>(AttachedProperty<T> property, T value)` типизированный, неявные преобразования типов срабатывают, но получается лес из скобочек.