# Дизайн API: Синтаксис для инициализации прикреплённых свойств

Tags: c#, .net, дизайн-api

Пытаюсь выбрать синтаксис для инициализации прикреплённых свойств в своей библиотеке [CsConsoleFormat](https://github.com/Athari/CsConsoleFormat). Прикреплённые свойства выполняют ту же роль, что и в WPF.

Вот, какие варианты нарисовались. В силу разных причин ни один не нравится.

1. **Индексатор** (а.к.а. инициализатор словаря):

   ```
   var a = new Element {
       Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5,
       [Element.FooProperty] = 2.1, [Element.BazProperty] = Guid.NewGuid()
   };
   a.WritePropertyValues();
   ```

   *Плюсы:*

   1. Выглядит симпатично, почти как инициализация обычных свойств.
   2. Сочетается с инициализатором объекта на одном уровне.
   3. Работает не только инициализация, но и чтение, и запись.
   4. В Avalonia UI используется похожий синтаксис для биндингов.

   *Минусы:*

   1. Один, но жирный: индексаторы не могут быть обобщёнными, поэтому никакой проверки типов, везде `object`. Причём теряется не только проверка, но и конвертация.
2. **Инициализатор коллекции** с двумя аргументами:

   ```
   var b = new Element {
       Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5,
       Values = { { Element.FooProperty, 2 }, { Element.BarProperty, "Hello!" } }
   };
   b.WritePropertyValues();
   ```

   *Плюсы:*

   1. Строго типизировано.
   2. Можно совместить с индексатором для чтения и записи.

   *Минусы:*

   1. Инициализаторы коллекций и объектов не совмещаются, приходится выделять на отдельный уровень.
   2. Выглядит сомнительно из-за леса из фигурных скобочек: в конце выражения их аж три штуки.
   3. Если добавлять индексатор для чтения и записи, то получается мешанина: в одном месте типизировано, в другом нет.
3. **Инициализатор коллекции** с одним аргументом в сочетании с оператором:

   ```
   var c = new Element {
       Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5,
       Values = { Element.FooProperty == 10, Element.BazProperty == Guid.NewGuid() }
   };
   c.WritePropertyValues();
   ```

   *Плюсы:*

   1. Строго типизировано.
   2. Синтаксис умеренно краткий и умеренно приятный.
   3. Можно совместить с индексатором для чтения и записи.

   *Минусы:*

   1. Оператор присваивания не перегружается, приходится перегружать самый низкоприоритетный бинарный оператор, а он уже достаточно высоко, чтобы портить некоторые выражения (`Element.BoolProperty == a == b`).
   2. Равенство для имитации присваивания — не самый логичный ход. Не хочется оказаться в роли "изобретателя" оператора `>>` в C++. Впрочем, в Avalonia UI позволяют играться с операторами, почему бы и мне не.
   3. Если добавлять индексатор для чтения и записи, то получается мешанина: в одном месте типизировано, в другом нет.
4. Старый-добрый **fluent**:

   ```
   var d = new Element {
           Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5
       }
       .Set(Element.FooProperty, 1337).Set(Element.BarProperty, "World!");
   d.WritePropertyValues();
   ```

   *Плюсы:*

   1. Строго типизировано.
   2. Можно совместить с симметричным методом `Get`.
   3. Если совмещать с `Get`, то операции симметричные и однообразные.

   *Минусы:*

   1. Синтаксис кошмарный и ужасный, если нужно использовать и обычные, и прикреплённые свойства (перенести все свойства в fluent — не вариант).

Код, реализующий все синтаксисы, описанные выше:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Element {
            Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5,
            [Element.FooProperty] = 2.1, [Element.BazProperty] = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
        a.WritePropertyValues();

        var b = new Element {
            Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5,
            Values = { { Element.FooProperty, 2 }, { Element.BarProperty, "Hello!" } }
        };
        b.WritePropertyValues();

        var c = new Element {
            Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5,
            Values = { Element.FooProperty == 10, Element.BazProperty == Guid.NewGuid() }
        };
        c.WritePropertyValues();

        var d = new Element {
                Oops = 1, I = 2, Did = 3, It = 4, Again = 5
            }
            .Set(Element.FooProperty, 1337).Set(Element.BarProperty, "World!");
        d.WritePropertyValues();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class Element
{
    public static readonly Property<int> FooProperty = Property.Register("Foo", 1);
    public static readonly Property<string> BarProperty = Property.Register("Bar", "a");
    public static readonly Property<Guid> BazProperty = Property.Register("Baz", Guid.Empty);

    private readonly Dictionary<Property, object> _properties = new Dictionary<Property, object>();

    public int Oops { get; set; }
    public int I { get; set; }
    public int Did { get; set; }
    public int It { get; set; }
    public int Again { get; set; }
    public Values Values { get; }

    public Element()
    {
        Values = new Values(this);
    }

    public object this[Property property]
    {
        get => _properties.TryGetValue(property, out object value) ? value : property.DefaultValueUntyped;
        set => _properties[property] = value;
    }

    public Element Set<T>(Property<T> prop, T v)
    {
        _properties[prop] = v;
        return this;
    }

    public void WritePropertyValues()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Property, object> property in _properties)
            Console.WriteLine($"{property.Key.Type.Name} {property.Key.Name} = {property.Value} (default: {property.Key.DefaultValueUntyped})");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

internal class Values : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly Element _element;
    public Values(Element element) => _element = element;
    public void Add<T>(Property<T> prop, T v) => _element[prop] = v;
    public void Add<T>(PropertyValue<T> pv) => _element[pv.Property] = pv.Value;
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => null;
}

internal abstract class Property
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public object DefaultValueUntyped { get; }
    public abstract Type Type { get; }

    protected Property(string name, object defaultValueUntyped)
    {
        Name = name;
        DefaultValueUntyped = defaultValueUntyped;
    }

    public static Property<T> Register<T>(string name, T defaultValue) => new Property<T>(name, defaultValue);
}

internal class Property<T> : Property
{
    public T DefaultValue => (T)DefaultValueUntyped;
    public override Type Type => typeof(T);

    internal Property(string name, T defaultValue) : base(name, defaultValue)
    { }

    public static PropertyValue<T> operator ==(Property<T> property, T value) => new PropertyValue<T>(property, value);
    public static PropertyValue<T> operator !=(Property<T> property, T value) => default;
}

internal struct PropertyValue<T>
{
    public Property Property { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public PropertyValue(Property property, T value)
    {
        Property = property;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Возможно, я упускаю как-то более удобный вариант из виду? Есть ещё какие-нибудь альтернативы? Желательно строго типизированные и с кратким синтаксисом.

Мнения по поводу описанных выше вариантов тоже приветствуются.

Answer (score 2):

Лично мне нравится fluent вариант - то, что оно отделено от обычных свойств даже плюс (мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно). Но если вы хотите получить код короче, то вам придется изобретать конвенкции. Я подумал о анонимных классах, как их используют в asp.net mvc например.

```
var d = new Element
{
    Oops = 1,
    I = 2,
    Did = 3,
    It = 4,
    Again = 5
}   
.AddProperties<Element>(new 
{ 
    FooProperty = 10,
    BarProperty = "alkdjalkds",
    BazProperty = Guid.NewGuid()
});
```

Если уж сильно надо строгую типизацию, то можно как то так сделать

```
public static class Ext
{
    internal static T Value<T>(this Property<T> prop, T value)
    {
        return value; // тут можно придумать что то типа AttchedPropertyValue<T>, который можно создать только отсюда
    }   
}
```

Тогда

```
.AddProperties<Element>(new 
{ 
    FooProperty = Element.FooProperty.Value(10),
    BarProperty = Element.BarProperty.Value("alkdjalkds"),
    BazProperty = Element.BazProperty.Value(Guid.NewGuid())
});
```

Ну, и считать это все как то так

```
public Element AddProperties<T>(object b)
{
    var sourceType = typeof(T);
    foreach (var p in b.GetType().GetProperties())
    {   
        var fieldInfo = sourceType.GetField(p.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);             

        if (fieldInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("bla bla");

        var fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as Property;

        var value = p.GetValue(b);

        if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsGenericType)
        if (value.GetType()!=fieldInfo.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            throw new ArgumentException("bla bla bla");

        _properties[fieldValue] = value;
    }   

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Я не случайно пытаюсь разместить обычные и прикреплённые свойства рядом. Дело в том, что и те, и другие обычно *логически* следуют до описания подэлементов. Проблема более детально описана в ["первой части" вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/793695). Я реализовал предложенный в том ответе подход с инициализатором коллекции для подэлементов, поэтому, если переместить инициализацию прикреплённых свойств в метод, то окончательная последовательность получится "свойства, подэлементы, прикреплённые свойства", что неестественно.

Comment: У вас типизация не строгая, у вас всё динамическое, причём даже более динамическое, чем у меня. Я хочу, чтобы все проверки выполнялись при компиляции, а вы даже проверку имён свойств убираете во время исполнения. И автодополнение кода теряется. Так-то тип аругмента я и в индексаторе могу проверять.

Comment: @Athari про типизацию я, конечно, имел ввиду указание типизированных значений свойств (а не набора самих свойств). А так мне не очень ясно, как вы хотите иметь строгую типизацию всего во время компиляции, когда речь идет о словаре прикрепленных свойств? По моему динамика тут сама по себе напрашивается. А вот первый ваш вопрос я пропустил, да. Почитаю на досуге

Comment: Прикреплённые свойства не возникают динамически в рантайме, они уже существуют, описаны в статических свойствах, типизированы со всех сторон, просто их значения нужно "прикреплять" не к элементам, в классе которых они определены. (Что в моём примере всё запихано в один `Element` — это упрощение.) Например, контейнер `Grid` может определять прикреплённые свойства `Grid.Column` и `Grid.Row` для того, чтобы дочерние элементы могли указать, в какой ячейке их надо разместить. Свойства определены в `Grid`, а значения можно засунуть в любой дочерний элемент, который про `Grid` ничего не знает.

Comment: Да, я знаю что это такое. Я к тому, что вы хотите иметь набор свойств, а обращаться с ними так, как будто они свойства объекта - по моему это если и выполнимая (в чем я сомневаюсь), то очень непростая задача. А если оглядываться на WPF, то там я подозреваю вообще динамика на динамике. Я к тому, что ваша задача скорее всего статически типизированного в полном смысла слова решения не имеет и вам все равно придется идти на какие то компромиссы. Однако, почитав ваш первый вопрос я согласен, что fluent будет там выглядеть не к месту.

Answer (score 2):

У меня тоже вариант с `Value`:

```
internal class Property<T> : Property
{
    // ...
    public PropertyValue<T> Value(T t) => new PropertyValue<T>(this, t);
}
```

и синтаксисом

```
var e = new Element
{
    Oops = 1,
    I = 2,
    Did = 3,
    It = 4,
    Again = 5,
    Values = { Element.FooProperty.Value(10), Element.BazProperty.Value(Guid.NewGuid()) }
};
```

Сильная типизация в наличии. Синтаксис не очень.

---

Ещё один вариант с сильной типизацией, за счёт более сложного определения attached property (которое, впрочем, можно вынести в snippet):

```
var f = new Element
{
    Oops = 1,
    I = 2,
    Did = 3,
    It = 4,
    Again = 5,
    Values = { (Element.Foo)10, (Element.Baz)Guid.NewGuid() }
};
```

Достигается следующим изменением кода:

```
interface IPropertyValue<T>
{
    Property Property { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

internal struct PropertyValue<T> : IPropertyValue<T>
{
    // остальное как было
}

internal class Values : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly Element _element;
    public Values(Element element) => _element = element;
    public void Add<T>(Property<T> prop, T v) => _element[prop] = v;
    // заменили на интерфейс
    public void Add<T>(IPropertyValue<T> pv) => _element[pv.Property] = pv.Value;
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => null;
}
```

И определение:

```
internal class Element
{
    public static readonly Property<int> FooProperty = Property.Register("Foo", 1);
    public struct Foo : IPropertyValue<int>
    {
        public Property Property => Element.FooProperty;
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public static explicit operator Foo(int value) => new Foo() { Value = value };
    }

    public static readonly Property<string> BarProperty = Property.Register("Bar", "a");
    public struct Bar : IPropertyValue<string>
    {
        public Property Property => Element.BarProperty;
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public static explicit operator Bar(string value) => new Bar() { Value = value };
    }

    public static readonly Property<Guid> BazProperty = Property.Register("Baz", Guid.Empty);
    public struct Baz : IPropertyValue<Guid>
    {
        public Property Property => Element.BazProperty;
        public Guid Value { get; set; }
        public static explicit operator Baz(Guid value) => new Baz() { Value = value };
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<Property, object> _properties =
        new Dictionary<Property, object>();
    // дальше как было
```

Comment: Я так не стал предлагать, так как, по сути, получается что `FooProperty` можно хоть 10 раз добавить в одном инициализаторе

Comment: @tym32167: Это да. А можно ли с этим бороться?

Comment: @tym32167 Любопытное замечание насчёт повторного присваивания. На всякий случай добавил проверку в [todo](https://github.com/Athari/CsConsoleFormat/issues/5), чтобы не забыть. Но вообще эта проблема менее критична, чем откладывание падения из-за присваивания а-ля `int a = "foo"` до времени исполнения.

Comment: @VladD Синтаксически не худший вариант: леса скобочек нет, выравнивание ровное. Жалко, что в C# нельзя перегрузить ни `operator()`, ни `operator=`.

Comment: @VladD Кстати, а мой [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/793695) видели? В принципе тема ещё не закрыта, версию 1.0 я ещё не релизнул, поэтому я открыт для предложений.

Comment: @Athari: Добавил ещё один вариант.

Comment: @tym32167 Кстати, для статистики, `new Dictionary<int, int> { [1] = 2, [1] = 3 }` не считается синтаксической ошибкой.

Comment: @Athari: Вопрос не видел, сейчас почитаю.

Comment: @VladD Второй вариант уже объявление прикреплённых свойств превращает в запредельный ужас. В отличие от WPF, это не то чтобы часто надо делать потребителю библиотеки, но за разумные рамки выходить всё же не хотелось бы.

Comment: @Athari: Это да, но можно запихнуть в сниппет и окружить `#region`'ом. К сожалению, нету статического наследования, а то можно было бы упростить.

Comment: @Athari ну, для Dictionary все понятно, но если в XAML присоединить одно свойство 2 раза, то будет ошибка