# Есть ли в c# свойство, которое обязывает вызывать метод предка при его переопределении?

Tags: c#, unity3d, наследование, скрипт

А вот кто знает, есть ли в c# (Unity3D) свойство, которое обязывает вызывать метод предка при его переопределении?

Метод, который хочется отслеживать - OnDestroy. Вызывается при уничтожении объекта. Соответственно нужен в обоих скриптах и разделить его никак не получится.

Смысл прост.
Переопределили не посмотрев на предка, слетел функционал.
Большой вопрос в том как это предотвратить? (административные методы не помогут)

Может в райдере настроить линтер как-то можно?
Например добавить свойство и некую реакцию на него?

```
class parent
{
 
  protected  virtual void OnDestroy()
  {
     // some happens
  }
}
 
class child : parent
{
  protected  override void OnDestroy()
  {
     // Ошибка, потому как нет вызова base.OnDestroy();
 
  }
 
}
```

Comment: Нет, такого свойства нет.

Comment: Вы хотите видеть ошибку на этапе компиляции в случае, если метод M1 потомка не вызывает базовую реализацию? Насколько я знаю, такого C# не умеет

Comment: Мне хочется не терять функционал базового метода при его переопределении.

Comment: Если вам реально нужна гарантия, напишите анализатор. Я покажу, как, если будет время.

Comment: @VladD ого кто тут :-) Напишите, вопрос все равно не двигается в сторону разрешения.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников: Ага, я написал анализатор, вечером попробую оформить ответ.

Comment: Я думаю, что один из ответов уже можно отметить принятым. Галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 9):

Гарантировать этого вы не можете. Это противоречит самой идеи виртуальных методов. Но, вы можете изменить шаблон таким образом, что бы вызов определенного метода не зависел от качества памяти программиста:

```
abstract class Parent
{
    public void foo()
    {
        bar();
        M1();
    }

    protected abstract void M1();

    private void bar()
    {
        // Важный базовый функционал
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    protected override void M1()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Теперь, описываемое вами поведение имплементировано в методе `foo`.

---

Хорошо, если вопрос ставить следующим образом: можно без изменения дизайна как-то гарантировать вызов базового класса, то ответ — нет (если это не конструктор, конечно). Да и как бы это работало? Цепочка наследования может быть гораздо глубже чем Base → Derived и как бы регулировался этот вызов? Единственная, насколько мне известная, возможность осуществить невиртуальный вызов это `base.Method()`

Остальные возможности язык оставляет вам и они связаны с изменением дизайна. От шаблонного класса до [цепочки обязанностей](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/3.7.php).

---

И последнее, если кто-то проектирует базовый класс в котором есть важный-важный метод `onDestroy` вызов которого *обязателен* (по вашим словам) и делает этот метод *виртуальным!* то, может, проблема лежит в некоторой другой плоскости? :-)

Comment: Наверное стоило уточнить, что вопрос о методе OnDestroy , который является системным. И нужен в обоих скриптах.

Comment: И? :-) Если нельзя наследоваться (или не нужно) то есть композиция/аггрегация. Никто вам не мешает написать шаблон.

Comment: Наследоваться можно, но обязательно нужно вызывать метод предка.

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что такой подход называется паттерн [Шаблонный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблонный_метод_(шаблон_проектирования))

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите, сам компилятор такого делать не умеет, это не включено в стандарт языка. Но компилятору можно помочь при помощи анализатора. Я напишу код, а чтобы понять его и переработать под свои требования, придётся погрузиться синтаксический разбор, семантические модели и связанные с ними вещи.

Итак, давайте вооружимся вот этими полезными статьями:

- [How to write a Roslyn Analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/)
- [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

а также можно посмотреть в этот немного устаревший ответ:

- [Иерархия наследования интерфейсов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/756891).

Установим нужные пакеты в Visual Studio и создадим проект типа Analyzer with Code Fix. Никакого хорошего Code Fix придумать нельзя: как именно вызывать метод базового класса, должен осознанно решить сам программист, поэтому у нас Code Fix не будет.

У нас получатся 5 проектов в Visual Studio, из которых проект с code fix я удалил (и сделал другие очевидные изменения в source.extension.vsixmanifest и CallBaseAnalyzer.Package.csproj, чтобы всё компилировалось):

[image: Solution Explorer]

Самое интересное — код анализатора — лежит в первом проекте. Его код заменяем на вот такой: (пояснения к коду даны по ходу в комментариях)

```cs
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

namespace CallBaseAnalyzer
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class CallBaseAnalyzerAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        public const string DiagnosticId = "CallBaseAnalyzer";

        private static readonly string Title = "Base virtual function not called";
        private static readonly string MessageFormat =
            "The override of function {0} must call base";
        private static readonly string Description =
            "The virtual function override must call the base function";
        private const string Category = "Reliability";

        // соберём описание нашего правила
        private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule =
            new DiagnosticDescriptor(
                DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category,
                DiagnosticSeverity.Error, // укажен, что это ошибка, а не предупреждение
                isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics =>
            ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
            context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

            // будет вызвано для каждого метода
            context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SymbolKind.Method);
        }

        private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
        {
            // получаем символ
            var methodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)context.Symbol;

            // если это не переопределение, нам не интересно
            if (!methodSymbol.IsOverride)
                return;

            // получаем тот метод, который переопределён
            // (он должен быть вызван в теле метода, мы будем это проверять)
            var overriddenMethod = methodSymbol.OverriddenMethod;

            // спускаемся до синтаксического дерева, получаем тело метода
            var declaringSyntaxes = methodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences;
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/38294041/276994
            // обыно дожно быть одно, для partial-методов два,
            // если метод из метаданных (ref. assembly), то ноль
            if (declaringSyntaxes.Count() == 0)
                return;

            bool foundBaseCall = false;

            foreach (var declaringSyntax in declaringSyntaxes)
            {
                var methodTopSyntaxNode = declaringSyntax.GetSyntax();
                // ищем все ссылки на базовый класс (base)
                var baseMentionSyntaxes =
                        methodTopSyntaxNode.DescendantNodes()
                                           .OfType<BaseExpressionSyntax>();
                foreach (var baseMentionSyntax in baseMentionSyntaxes)
                {
                    // найдём включающий его вызов метода поиском вверх до вершины метода
                    InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationNode = null;
                    for (SyntaxNode curr = baseMentionSyntax.Parent;
                         curr != methodTopSyntaxNode;
                         curr = curr.Parent)
                    {
                        if (curr is InvocationExpressionSyntax ies)
                        {
                            invocationNode = ies;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (invocationNode == null) // не нашли? к следующему base
                        continue;

                    // даже если нашли какой-то вызов, надо ещё проверить,
                    // а тот ли это вызов, что нам нужно
                    // получаем символ у семантической модели
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/30721617/276994
                    var semanticModel =
                        context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(invocationNode.SyntaxTree);
                    var symInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocationNode);
                    // берём метод, который вызывается данным вызовом
                    var innerMethodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)symInfo.Symbol;
                    // если его нет (например, у нас некомпилирующийся код), отваливаем
                    if (innerMethodSymbol == null)
                        return;

                    // сравниваем с тем, который мы ищем
                    if (SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(innerMethodSymbol,
                                                              overriddenMethod))
                    {
                        foundBaseCall = true; // окей, вызов именно базового метода
                        break; // выходим, дальше искать нечего
                    }
                }

                if (foundBaseCall)
                    break;  // выходим, дальше искать нечего
            }

            // если результаты поисков отрицательные...
            if (!foundBaseCall)
            {
                // выдаём диагностическое сообщение
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule,
                                                   methodSymbol.Locations[0],
                                                   methodSymbol.Name);
                context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не забываем про unit-тесты, благо проект с ними любезно создал для нас wizard:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class CallBaseAnalyzerUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task OverrideIsCalled()
    {
        var test = @"
namespace Test
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        protected virtual int GetValue() => 1;
    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        protected override int GetValue()
        {
            if (1 > 0) return 5; else return base.GetValue();
        }
    }
}";

        await VerifyCS.VerifyAnalyzerAsync(test);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task OverrideIsNotCalled()
    {
        var test = @"
namespace Test
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        protected virtual int GetValue() => 1;
    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        protected override int {|#0:GetValue|}()
        {
            if (1 > 0) return 5; else return 6;
        }
    }
}";

        var expected = VerifyCS.Diagnostic("CallBaseAnalyzer")
                               .WithLocation(0)
                               .WithArguments("GetValue");
        await VerifyCS.VerifyAnalyzerAsync(test, expected);
    }
}
```

Запустим vsix-проект на выполнение, получим экспериментальный экземпляр Visual Studio, в котором применяется наш анализатор:

[image: Запись работы Студии]

---

В таком виде анализатор проверяет, чтобы базовая функция вызывалась *всегда*. Вам, наверное, хочется, чтобы это правило применялось лишь для некоторых базовых функций. Для этого нужно в анализатор добавить фильтр, который будет проверять, ту ли функцию мы анализируем.

Возможностей для этого есть много. Самый простой вариант — захардкодировать проверяемую функцию `OnDestroy`. Например, так. В класс-анализатор добавляем фильтрующий метод, который ограничивает проверки переопределениями метода `OnDestroy` класса `TestOuter.TestInner.BaseClass`:

```cs
private static bool FilterMethod(IMethodSymbol methodSymbol)
{
    if (methodSymbol.Name != "OnDestroy")
        return false;

    // ищем самый дальний переопределённый метод
    var topmostOverriddenSymbol = methodSymbol;
    while (topmostOverriddenSymbol.OverriddenMethod != null)
        topmostOverriddenSymbol = topmostOverriddenSymbol.OverriddenMethod;

    // проверяем, что этот метод:
    return topmostOverriddenSymbol is
    {
        ContainingType: // содержится прямо в типе...
        {
            Name: "BaseClass", // по имени BaseClass,
            ContainingSymbol:  // который содержится непосредственно в
            {
                Kind: SymbolKind.Namespace, // пространстве имён
                Name: "TestInner",          // TestInner
                ContainingSymbol:           // которое, в свою очередь, содержится в
                {
                    Kind: SymbolKind.Namespace, // пространстве имён
                    Name: "TestOuter",          // TestOuter
                    ContainingSymbol:           // которое, в свою очередь, содержится в
                    {
                        Kind: SymbolKind.Namespace,  // пространстве имён
                        CanBeReferencedByName: false // без имени (то есть, корневом)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

В методе `AnalyzeSymbol` дописываем применение фильтра:

```cs
private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    // получаем символ
    var methodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)context.Symbol;

    // если это не переопределение, нам не интересно
    if (!methodSymbol.IsOverride)
        return;

    if (!FilterMethod(methodSymbol))
        return;

    ...
```

Можно придумать более изящный путь, например, указывать нужные базовые методы при помощи атрибута, при этом фильтр тоже должен быть обновлён.

Вам понадобится подключить анализатор к проекту.

Если же вы компилируете ваш проект без Visual Studio, то, вероятно, вам захочется переделать код в статический анализатор, как рассказано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876456/10105).